# KSH: Split String into smaller substrings based on count

Tags: string, shell, split, ksh

KSH
HP-SOL-Lin
Cannot use xAWK

I have several strings that are quite long and i want to break them down into smaller substrings.

What I have

```
String = "word1 word2 word3 word4 .....wordx"
```

What I want

```
String1="word1 word2"
String2="word3 word4"
String3="word4 word5"
Stringx="wordx wordx+1"
etc.....
```

How Can i break this up to where if my string is longer than x words, break into smaller strings no longer than x? I have no idea how long each string will be. We can test for it, but it will not be consistent.

```
StrLen=`echo $string |wc -w`
```

Some strings are longer than 2000 words, so i cannot use a shell array as there is a max of 1024 fields.

### ideas?

Here is what I have come up with based on comments below

```
FIELDS=`echo $String | wc -w`
((n=$FIELDS/2+1))
i=1

while [[ $i -le $n ]]; do
typeset STRING$i=`echo $String | cut -d" " -f$CUTSTART-$CUTEND`
do stuff

i=`expr $i+1`
CUTSTART=`expr $CUTSTART+1`
CUTEND=`expr $CUTEND+1`
done
```

Still seem to be having issues with the typeset peice.
Assumptions

```
i=1
CUTSTART=1
CUTEND=2
String=one two three

myserver> typeset STRING=`echo $String | cut -d" " -f$CUTSTART-$CUTEND`
myserver> echo $STRING
myserver> one two
myserver>
myserver> typeset STRING$i=`echo $String | cut -d" " -f$CUTSTART-$CUTEND`
myserver> echo $STRING1
myserver> one
```

what is this issue with $i messing up my echo|cut command?

Comment: does your ksh respond to `echo ${.sh.version}` ? If not, see if you can find ksh93 or dtksh. I think that gives you more flexibility on the array size (not certain). Good luck.

Comment: @shelter here is the result 
`Version AJM 93t+ 2010-02-02`

Comment: Tnx for ksh version info. What do you mean in your first line descript "can't use xAWK"? gawk not installed? what about regular awk? It will be a one-liner if you can use awk. OR saying that you're limited to 1024 array elems sounds like numeric array notation. YOu can use number as keys to assoc arrays. I'd be surprized if there is a limit there. Then you just need to control the array from the outside using a number, but as a string in the assoc array. I.e. `typeset -A assocArr; assocArr["$((++i))"]="wrd1"`. Sorry have 2 leave. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a loop that uses `read` to extract two words at a time:

```
# Take advantage of the fact that ksh doesn't execute
# read in a subshell.
i=1
String="one two three four five six seven eight"
while echo $String | read w1 w2 w3; do
    typeset "String$i=$w1 $w2"
    if [ -z $w3 ]; then
        break;
    fi
    String=$w3
    let i=i+1
done
echo $String1
echo $String2
echo $String3
# etc.
```

Comment: I dont understand this? looks like this will only print the first two fields/words of each string. I need to pull out the entire string into 2 word substrings

Comment: The `typeset` command can be used to dynamically create a variable. After the loop exists, you should have a series of variables `String1`, `String2`, etc available for use.

Comment: I updated my OP with a temp solution based on this typset...was too difficult to post as a comment

Comment: What is it about this solution that doesn't work for you? It creates exactly the set of variables you asked for. Note that I'm quoting the entire argument to `typeset`, which seems to be necessary to avoid the problem mention in your update.